# actionmailer, sending mail to outlook group fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-2

Rails 2.3.18

Sending mail to an Outlook group address is not working.

```
recipients 'group_address@outlook.com'
```

This succeeds according to the log, but nothing is seen in any of the address inboxes that make up the group.

However this,

```
recipients 'user1@outlook.com, user2@outlook.com, user3@outlook.com'
```

is working.  I'm not sure what could be wrong here or what other information to give.  I'm guessing it might be an Outlook thing, any ideas are welcome, thanks.

Comment: You have probably already checked this but doesn't hurt to ask: The "group_address@outlook.com" you are referring to works just fine outside of the Rails app, correct? Sounds like an outlook or group issue with that email address, don't see why Rails would care if the email represents a group of emails or an individual email address.

Comment: yeah, I checked it and it's actively being used.